# Octave: hide window of a complex plot; print to file instead

Tags: windows, matlab, plot, octave

I'm trying to plot three curves in a same graphic using two independent y axes and one common x axis (two of the curves shared one y axis, the other have its own y axis, and the three of them share the same x axis).

The code is saved in a `.m` script, and I want to execute it, generate a `png` file with the plot without opening any plot window, and exit.

The code is as follow:

```
# data1 and data2 share the left Y axis.
# data3 use the right Y axis.
# The three of them share the X axis.
[data1, data2, data3] = textread("test.mat", "%u %u %u");

x = [1:1:length(data1)];

hold on
# f = figure('visible', 'off'); # This doesn't work or I don't know how to use it.

[both_axes, data1_curve, data3_curve] = plotyy(x, data1, x, data3);
data2_curve = plot(both_axes(1), x, data2);

set(both_axes, {'ycolor'}, {'r'; 'b'});

xlabel(both_axes(1), "X axis");

ylabel(both_axes(1), "Y axis 1");
set(data1_curve, 'color', 'red');
set(data2_curve, 'color', 'red');
set(data2_curve, 'linestyle', '--');

ylabel(both_axes(2), "Y axis 2");
set(data3, 'color', 'blue');

print "-S800,500" -dpng image.png
```

I execute it from terminal as follow (I'm on windows and that's the only way octave behaves correctly and ends the cli session when the script finishes):

```
$ octave-gui -i script.m
```

Currently, the script is executed correctly, it briefly shows the window with the plot, and when the png file is generated, `octave-gui` closes the window and exits.

I just want to never show the window.

Comment: Setting the visible property to off should do the trick (in MATLAB it does). Try using a different graphics backend in Octave, they each have different capabilities.